# How to add two UIImages to UITableView Background

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have two images with flowers for each side of the iPhone screen. I want to add these images to UITableView background.

### The screenshot

[image]

**The question is**: how to add it programmatically or using storyboard?
I want to use this flowers for each iPhone screen, is it possible? Or should I add it at each ViewController in storyboard?

### The code I made

```
UIImageView *leftFlowersIView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 455)];
    [leftFlowersIView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flower_left.png"]];
    [self.tableView.backgroundView addSubview:leftFlowersIView];
    UIImageView *rightFlowersIView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 36, 0, 36, 455)];
    [rightFlowersIView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flower_right.png"]];
    [self.tableView.backgroundView addSubview:rightFlowersIView];
```

I received a blank background.

```
[self.view addSubview:leftFlowersIView];
```

It works, but when I am scrolling down - the background is scrolling too.

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = leftFlowersIView;
```

The image is stretched to fill the screen.

Thanks in advance, Artem.

### The result is

```
    UIImageView *backgroundIView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];
    UIImageView *leftFlowersIView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 36, 455)];
    [leftFlowersIView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flower_left.png"]];
    [backgroundIView addSubview:leftFlowersIView];
    UIImageView *rightFlowersIView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 36, 0, 36, 455)];
    [rightFlowersIView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flower_right.png"]];
    [backgroundIView addSubview:rightFlowersIView];

    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundIView;
```

Comment: You can decrease width of you table and use background image in behind.

Comment: I've decreased the width for each my cells. Sure.

Comment: You can set frame of your table inside that flower frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can make a single image with frame equal to the table view frame, then just add below code:

tableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:yourimage];

Comment: Thanks for idea about a single image with screen frame.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of solving this is to set `-[UIColor clearColor]` as a property `-[UITableView backgroundColor]`, and then work with your two images:

1. Create new `UIImageView`, add it to `UIView` as a subview (**underneath** `UITableView`)
2. Add both corner images to one image with any graphical tool, except that between two images there'll be 1px **white** pixel (so that it'll be repeated)
3. Create an instance of `UIImage` with a new image asset
4. Create resizable `UIImage` with `-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:]`. You should specify UIEdgeInsetsMake(a,b,c,d), where:

   - a: top padding of the stretchable image (0 in your case)
   - b: left padding of the stretchable image (in your case it's width of one side of flower image asset)
   - c: bottom padding of the stretchable image (0 in your case)
   - d: right padding of the stretchable image (in your case it's width of one side of flower image asset)
5. Set resizable `UIImage` to `-[UIImageView image]` property

Reference regarding [`-[UIImage resizableImageWithCapInsets]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3a)